# 500 internal server error Perl CGI

Tags: perl

I have a problem with my Perl CGI. When executes a Perl script i see me a error:

Use of uninitialized value $params in split at videoplayback.pl line 4.

So, i we get me a error:

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Please fix.

This is my code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

$params= $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
@tokens=split('&', $params);

foreach $string (@tokens){ 

 @mess=split('=', $string);

 if(index($params, "audio")!=-1){
  if($mess[0] eq "range"){
   $range=$mess[1];
   $command="curl --header \"Range: bytes=${range}\" http://127.0.0.1/audio.mp4";

   print "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
   print "Content-Length: ", length($command), "\r\n";
   print "Last-Modified: Fri, 28 Jun 2013 14:34:55 GMT\r\n";
   print "Content-Type: audio/mp4\r\n";
   print "Date: Wed, 17 Jul 2013 14:28:52 GMT\r\n";
   print "Expires: Wed, 17 Jul 2013 14:28:52 GMT\r\nCache-Control: private, max-age=22303\r\nAccept-Ranges: bytes\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.youtube.com\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Credentials: true\r\nTiming-Allow-Origin: http://www.youtube.com\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nX-Content-Type-Options: nosniff\r\nServer: gvs 1.0\n\r\n";

   print `$command`;
  }
 }

 elsif(index($params, "video")!=-1){
  if($mess[0] eq "range"){
   print "Content-type: video/mp4\n\n";
   $range2=$mess[1];
   $command2="curl --header \"Range: bytes=${range2}\" http://127.0.0.1/planet_360.mp4";
   print `$command2`;
  }
 }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: To solve an internal Server error, it helps to take a look into Server logfiles

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and add the script. Then select the script with the mouse and click `{}` near `Bold` and *Italic* to format it as code.

Comment: You should also `chomp $string;`

Comment: The warning is unrelated to the internal server error. Your code (as posted here) does not generate that warning, but it's not valid CGI either. However, it's horribly unsafe (shell injection / arbitrary code execution) and should really start with `use strict; use warnings;` (and a module to deal with parameter parsing).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have anything in your environment variable 'QUERY_STRING'.
If you don't need that, you could do:

```
$params= $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'} ? $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'} : 'foo';
```

This will avoid having the error "Use of uninitialized value $params..".
You can test this also by doing

```
perl videoplayback.pl
```

in your console.

Answer (score 0):

Your CGI program expects query parameters. Query parameters are the (optional) bits of a URL that appear after the `?`. So in a URL that looks like this:

```
https://example.com/cgi/your_program.cgi?foo=1&bar=2
```

The query parameters are `foo=1&bar=2`.

Inside a CGI program, you access the query parameters by parsing them out of `$ENV{QUERY_STRING}`. That's what the first few lines of your program do.

But what happens if your program is called like this:

```
https://example.com/cgi/your_program.cgi
```

Then, there are no query parameters and there will be nothing in `$ENV{QUERY_STRING}`. That's what is generating the warning (and it's a warning, not an error) that you see. On line 4, you're trying to split `$params`, but `$params` has no data in it. Your program needs to deal with the case when it is passed no parameters.

But that's not what is killing your program. As I said, it's a warning, not an error. The error is caused by a different problem.

A CGI program is supposed to return two things - a set of headers and some content. You obviously know that as the bulk of your code is about printing headers and content. But what happens when there are no parameters? As `$params` is empty, `@tokens` will also contain no data. That means that your `foreach` loop body is never executed and no header ever gets returned.

I bet that your web server error log contains something along the lines of "no headers found".

A few more things to consider:

- Always add `use strict` and `use warnings` to your Perl code. And fix the problems they reveal (the most obvious one will be the need to declare all of your variables using `my`).
- Please think about using CGI.pm to parse your parameters and create your headers. There are complexities to this that you haven't considered. The people who wrote the module have considered them.
- A CGI program needs to emit exactly one set of headers. So putting your headers in a loop which can be executed zero times (as we have currently) or multiple times, seems strange. You'll want to reconsider this logic.
- Taking input from a user (e.g. `range`) and passing that directly to an operating system command is a recipe for disaster. Please ensure you clean up the user's input before using it in this way.